# "Figment" other than in "figment of the imagination"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

Are there any recurring uses of the word "figment" other than in the expression "figment of the imagination"?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I wonder if "Figment" would make a good name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly. "Figment" can be used [as these examples show:](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=figment&use1913=on)

> Social figments, feints, and formalism.
> ~ *Mrs. Browning.*
>
> It carried rather an appearance of figment and invention . . . than of truth and reality.
> ~*Woodward.*

As you said, it's *commonly* used in "figment of imagination", but [its definition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/figment)—

> fabrication, fantasy, invention; something fictitious

—means it can be used everywhere really, to signify "anything fictitious."

Answer (score 3):

From http://vocabulary-vocabulary.com/dictionary/figment.php

It's most commonly used as a critique, in the phrase "figment of your imagination." To use figment in a different context, without that common phrase, is a good way of intellectualizing it. Biographical and historical figments are invented or feigned stories.

> Was that a figment, or did I just see
>   my estranged brother. (chimera,
>   illusion)
>
> Either that was a very real-to-life
>   figment, or I just saw a bald eagle
>   flying outside our window.
>   (fabrication, illusion)

Comment: It is very rare outside that expression. Jack Cohen and Ian Stewart wrote a book called "Figments of Reality", playing on that rarity.

Comment: @Colin I'd not agree with the 'very' (but then 10 years is a fairly long time even in linguistics). Vocabulary.com cherry-picks to show different usages (2 standalone out of 4); [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/figment) (2021) gives, I believe, an unskewed sampling, with 3 standalone out of 16 examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. It seems you're right. The iWeb corpus shows 4498 instances of _figment_, but only 2379 of them followed within 5 words by _imagination_: not the result I was expecting.